Система ролей и привилегий на C#
Как на C# можно сделать тонко настраиваемую систему прав и привилегий (Пример на картинке)? Как я понял, это можно сделать, работая с битами.


Да, можно битами:
[Flags]
enum Rights {
    None = 0,
    Editing = 1,
    Creation = 2,
    Copying = 4,
    Making = 8,
    CancelingMake = 16,
    // ...
    All = Int32.MinValue // for up to 32 rights
}

Rights currentRights = Rights.All;
var allowed = currentRights.HasFlag(Rights.Creation); // true 

Enum Class.

Можно, но хардкод - это хардкод. Если набор прав фиксированный на проектном уровне, то можно, а если планируется расширение, то не стоит.

@aepot Дальше - как позволит фантазия: хочешь - храни в базе; хочешь - в настройках приложения. Надо забацать на досуге. Полность избавиться от хардкода не получится, так как разрешения связаны с операциями, а операции жёстко запрограммированы.
